# Oracle PL/SQL get type of argument including constraints

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package and a function inside:

```
subtype boolean2 is boolean not null;

function test return boolean2 is
begin
    return true;
end;
```

I want to get the type of the return value. So I did the following query:

```
select * from all_arguments where object_name='TEST';
```

The resulting type is `boolean`. How can I get the type *with* the constraint? Or is there a separate query to only get the constraints?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as a "not null" return type.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure you can..

if you have identifiers compiled in you can see that it is returning a subtype and not a regular Boolean. but it doesn't give you the restrictions.
you could potentially join that back to _source and parse out the constraint yourself.. but that seems like a bad idea.

see below for a modified example

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS= 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

create or replace package x as

subtype boolean2 is boolean not null;

function test return boolean2;
function test2 return boolean;

end;
/

create or replace package body x as

function test return boolean2 is
begin
    return true;
end;

function test2 return boolean is
begin
    return true;
end;

end;
/

select * from USER_arguments
where package_name = 'X';

select * from USER_identifiers
where object_name = 'X'
order by object_type,line,col;
```